# Retrieving S3 objects from authenticated users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm having trouble with what should be a simple feature, but I can't figure out what guidelines to follow. I have a React web app and I want users to be able to do the following:

1. Authenticate through an AWS signin page
2. Retrieve S3 bucket names
3. Retrieve S3 objects in a given bucket
4. Retrieve S3 object given bucket name, object key

I know that you can do this by adding an IAM role manually through the AWS console, but I don't want users to have to do this. I want to be able to programmatically access their S3 buckets. I looked into using AWS Cognito, but as far as I can tell, that's for authenticating users and authorizing access to data that you own, not for the app to access buckets that the users own. Is there a way to do this? I'm just very lost after spending hours reading AWS guides and getting nowhere.

Comment: This is not going to work properly without the user doing some (manual) work on their end first. They should certainly NOT log in as their regular user and then let you do stuff on their behalf because the chances are VERY HIGH that their user can do a lot more than just view S3 buckets. Instead they should create a role in their account that is assumable by you and give that role access to a limited number of resources. Alternatively they can create a service user with the same restrictions and give you the access keys for that user.

Comment: What is the usecase for this, why do you want this, do you know of the security implications of this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways for a 'user' to interact with AWS:

- **Option 1:** **Send all requests via your app**, which determines whether the user is entitled to access data. If so, the app sends all the data back to the user. This does *not* involve giving the users any AWS credentials.
- **Option 2:** The user is authenticated (somehow) and is then **given AWS temporary credentials** that grant limited access to AWS (eg ability to access a specific bucket and path).

There is a 3rd option, which is to **give each user a set of IAM User credentials**, but this is rarely a good idea. It might be used where you have a limited set of users (eg a few close partner companies that regularly upload/download data), but certainly shouldn't be done with end-users of an application.

**The most common scenario is #1**, where users interact directly with your app. This lets you add features and potentially change cloud providers without impacting users. Your back-end can generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects stored in Amazon S3. Your back-end is fully responsible for confirming that users are permitted to access these objects and for generating the pre-signed URLs.

If you really want to issue AWS credentials to the users (or their browser), then your back-end application should use the [AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html) to **generate temporary credentials** with the desired permissions. These credentials can then be used with standard AWS API calls to access AWS services such as Amazon S3, without going via your app. They will need to first authenticate to your back-end, which will generate the credentials for them. They will *not* use the AWS sign-in page, since they do not actually have any AWS credentials.

Amazon Cognito can provide several of these capabilities, such as authentication and automatic assumption of an IAM Role, providing back temporary credentials that can be used in the front-end.

Comment: Don't all three options miss the point of the question because they let the app grant the user access but OP wants the user to grant the app access? OP wants *"the app to access buckets that the users own"*.

Comment: Oh! So, if the users are bringing the _own_ AWS account (as opposed to using the OP's AWS account), then they can just use the AWS credentials (Access Key, Secret Key) they already have. Perhaps the OP doesn't know about Access Keys and Secret Keys for API calls? I agree with your comment that users would be a little silly to give the access to somebody else's app.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! In response to @luk2302, the use case is that I'm trying to implement S3 integration into a web app so that users can load csv's that have been stored in S3 buckets. Later on, my goal would be to also allow users to download tabular data from other data stores like RDS.

I will look into Access Keys and Secret Keys for API calls. I just want the least head-ache-y way of reading users' buckets and objects, potentially without having them do anything but sign in.

Comment: Edit: It looks like there's a [way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-export-examples) to export RDS data from some instances to S3, so I guess implementing only S3 integration will be fine for now

Comment: @Random_User The number of services really is not the issue here but you need to consider my first comment under the question and the comment by John here: a user should not grant their access to you, they need to setup something to let you access the very limited set of resources that you need access to using a specific role or service user.

Comment: @luk2302 yeah that sounds like exactly what I need. I'm thinking I should just have the root user provide access keys to an IAM user, and leave it to the root user to configure the IAM user to have only read-only access to S3